# Unit testing Vuejs JSX components with composition api with jest. Issues with mounting and assertions

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jsx, vue-composition-api

I am trying to test a jsx component by passing props to it and asserting that it renders them correctly. This fails though for a reason I cannot understand. Here's the component

```js
// components/toast.tsx

import { createComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";
import style from "./toast.module.scss";
export default createComponent({
  name: "Toast",
  props: {
    message: String
  },
  setup(props) {
    return () => (
      <div class={style.toast}>
        <p>{props.message}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Here's the snippet of the unit test that is failing:

```js
// tests/unit/components/toast.spec.ts

import Toast from "@/components/toast";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";

// ... a describe block

  it("should render props correctly", () => {
    const msg = "hello";
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Toast, {
      propsData: {
        message: msg
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg);
  });
```

And the output from the failing test is here:

```
Expected substring: "hello"
    Received string:    "function (el) {
          var obj;·
          var args = [], len = arguments.length - 1;
          while ( len-- > 0 ) args[ len ] = arguments[ len + 1 ];
          if (shouldNotBeStubbed(el, stubs, modifiedComponents)) {
            return originalCreateElement.apply(void 0, [ el ].concat( args ))
          }·
          if (isConstructor(el) || isComponentOptions(el)) {
            if (stubAllComponents) {
              var stub = createStubFromComponent(el, el.name || 'anonymous', _Vue);
              return originalCreateElement.apply(void 0, [ stub ].concat( args ))
            }
            var Constructor = shouldExtend(el, _Vue) ? extend(el, _Vue) : el;·
            return originalCreateElement.apply(void 0, [ Constructor ].concat( args ))
          }·
          if (typeof el === 'string') {
            var original = resolveComponent(el, originalComponents);·
            if (!original) {
              return originalCreateElement.apply(void 0, [ el ].concat( args ))
            }·
            if (isDynamicComponent(original)) {
              return originalCreateElement.apply(void 0, [ el ].concat( args ))
            }·
            var stub$1 = createStubIfNeeded(stubAllComponents, original, _Vue, el);·
            if (stub$1) {
              Object.assign(vm.$options.components, ( obj = {}, obj[el] = stub$1, obj));
              modifiedComponents.add(el);
            }
          }·
          return originalCreateElement.apply(void 0, [ el ].concat( args ))
        }"

      16 |     });
      17 |     expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
    > 18 |     expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg);
         |                            ^
      19 |   });
      20 | });
      21 | 

      at Object.it (tests/unit/components/toast.spec.ts:18:28)
```

Everything works! except for this one part. If I use a single file component (`.vue`) the component mounts and the test passes with no problem.